# Limit checkbox select and move the selection to the first choice

Tags: jquery, html, input, checkbox

The goal is to make selection limitation for a list of checkbox inputs.
See the code there are three checkboxes and jquery makes limitation to selecting maximum of two out of the three. But I would like to have the limitation so that when two check boxes are selected and the user tries to click on the third unselected box, that would change the first selection to the third box.

http://jsfiddle.net/EYJj8/

```
<input type="checkbox" class="check" name="check1" id="check1" >
<label class="layout" for="check1"></label>

<input type="checkbox" class="check" name="check2" id="check2" >
<label class="layout" for="check2"></label>

<input type="checkbox" class="check" name="check3" id="check3" >
<label class="layout" for="check3"></label>

$("input:checkbox").click(function() {
var bol = $("input:checkbox:checked").length >= 2;     
$("input:checkbox").not(":checked").attr("disabled",bol);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that case you'd need to implement a state variable to keep track of in which order the boxes were checked. That could look something like this:

```
var checkState = [];

$("input:checkbox").click(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        checkState.push(this);
        if(checkState.length > 2)
            $(checkState.shift()).prop('checked',false);
    } else {
        var ix = checkState.indexOf(this);
        if(ix > -1) checkState.splice(ix,1);
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vmsKe/)

If you don't want to use an array in that manner, you could add a timestamp to each checkbox as they're checked. It still becomes a bit messy when you're going to figure out which item to uncheck first, though:

```
$(":checkbox").change(function() {
    $box = $(this);
    $box.data('check-time', $box.is(':checked') ? (new Date().getTime()) : null);

    if($(':checkbox:checked').length > 2) {
        $(':checkbox:checked').sort(function(a,b) { 
            var aTime = $(a).data('check-time');
            var bTime = $(b).data('check-time');
            return aTime == bTime ? 0 : aTime < bTime ? -1 : 1;
        }).first().prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nkyaw/)

Comment: I was going to do a similar thing, but I was going to manually do the indexOf due to lack of IE8 support

Comment: +1, this is pretty much what I was putting together myself; albeit I'd suggest (as always...) using `this.checked` rather than using jQuery to do the same thing (since they both return a Boolean anyway and are equally cross-browser compatible so far as I'm aware).

Answer (score 1):

See this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/arvind07/YT8hk/)

```
$("input:checkbox").click(function () {
    if ($("input:checkbox:checked").length >= 3) {
        $("input:checkbox:checked").not(this).first().attr("checked", false);
    }
});
```

Comment: This unchecks the first checked checkbox it finds, not the checkbox that was first checked, which I think is what was requested.

Comment: True it not change te first checked.

Answer (score 0):

Just uncheck the first `checked` checkbox when the limit has been reached:

```
$checkboxes = $('input:checkbox');
$checkboxes.change(function() {
    if ($checkboxes.filter(':checked').length > 2) {
        $checkboxes.not(this).filter(':checked:first').prop('checked', false);   
    }
});
```

I've bound the `change` event instead of the `click` event so that if the checkboxes are checked via keypress for example, the code will still be executed.

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EYJj8/7/)

---

**edit**

If you want to uncheck the last checked element when the limit has been reached, you can do the following:-

```
var $checkboxes = $('input:checkbox'), lastChecked;
$checkboxes.change(function() {
    if ($checkboxes.filter(':checked').length > 2) {
        $(lastChecked).prop('checked', false); 
    }
    if (this.checked) {
        lastChecked = this;   
    }
});
```

So when a checkbox is checked, and the limit has been reached, the previously checked checkbox will be unchecked.

#### [Here's another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EYJj8/8/)

Comment: `:checked:first` yields the first DOM node that happens to be checked, not the DOM node that was first checked regardless of its position in the DOM, which I think is what was requested.

Comment: @DavidHedlund you're probably right, the last sentence in the question led me to believe otherwise, though